# Adding Utility Classes to the Body Tag

Tags: tailwind-css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-green-400 h-screen">
test

</body>
</html>
```

Doesn't work. What can be the reason for this?
Any of the utility classes added to the body tag won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample HTML doesn't include a stylesheet, so the `bg-green-400` and `h-screen` classes aren't defined.

In production you should use a proper purged CSS file, but for testing you can load Tailwind from a CDN using this:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here's a fiddle of your HTML with this stylesheet included, and both of the classes you've used are working: https://jsfiddle.net/vrung30L/

Comment: Your code works. I wonder why it is not working here
https://play.tailwindcss.com/XLfpavD9LR

Comment: @zaster It looks like the entire code you enter in the Tailwind Play editor gets placed in a <body> tag on the right, so it doesn't seem to be possible to accomplish your particular requirement using Tailwind Play, but you should be fine to use classes on the body tag elsewhere.